# Import _tkinter or tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

All tutorials simply `import tkinter`,

I am wondering, though, why not `import _tkinter`? If my understanding is correct, `_tkinter` is the actual library in cpython and `tkinter` is the interface or API.

I am simply trying to grasp the paradigm as I read through some of the tkinter source code. It seems there is some python black magic afoot.

Comment: I think your understanding is correct.

Comment: Just open the tkinter/__init__.py file to see all of the code that `tkinter` provides. You'd have to do all that manually if you used `import _tkinter`. Use `import tkinter; print(tkinter.__file__)` to find the file.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`_tkinter` is a C-based module that wraps an internal tcl/tk interpreter. When you import it, and it only, you get access to this interpreter *but you do not get access to any of the python classes*.

You certainly can import `_tkinter`, but then you would have to recreate all of the python interfaces to the tcl/tk functions.

Answer (score 2):

In python "_" marks a variable is intended for internal use

This convention is defined in PEP 8, but isn't enforced by Python

You shouldn't import class/modules/variables starting with "_" due to that nature, the developer should allow a property/setter methods to access those attributes..

For python2 use "Tkinter"

For python3 use "tkinter"

http://pep8.org/#descriptive-naming-styles

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/tkinter.html#tkinter-modules),

> The Tk interface is located in a binary module named `_tkinter`. This module contains the low-level interface to Tk, and should never be used directly by application programmers.

So the somewhat unsatisfying answer to "why not import _tkinter?" is "because the language developers told us not to".

Comment: Unsatisfying is an understatement. What do we do as soon as someone says, "Don't do --fill in the blank--"?