# No module named '_tkinter' on Mac using Python 3

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to bundle my script into a .app using Tkinter as the GUI and the wrapper that does the bundling is Platypus.

I'm getting this error when I go to run the app.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/samb/Desktop/Beta1.app/Contents/Resources/script", line 4, in <module>
  import tkinter
File "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/P...ework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/tkinter/__init__.py", line 36, in <module>
  import _tkinter # If this fails your Python may not be configured for Tk
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_tkinter'
```

I'm running Python 3.7.4 on this machine, and my script uses:

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import filedialog
```

which should make it compatible. The script works when I run it using terminal, just not when I run the app.

[image: Platypus]

I've specified in the bundling app that it should use python3 as well...

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: I've only just begun using tkinter but I thought it was something that come with Python? EDIT: plus it seems to run in terminal when I type python3 and the file path of the script - does that confirm tkinter is installed correctly within python3?

Comment: You don't have to use `import _tkinter`, read [Import _tkinter or tkinter?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48385739/7414759)

Comment: My script isn't using ```import _tkinter``` maybe the wrapper is?

Answer (score 0):

Several problems: There is no file at `/usr/bin/python3`. Either use `/usr/local/bin/python3` or `/usr/bin/env` with `python3` as args. Or whatever your particular python environment needs.

For some reason, python is looking for the library inside Xcode, which is unusual. I have python3 installed and there's no python in

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/
```

On my installation, the valid filepath is:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/tkinter/__init__.py
```

(i.e. in /Library, not inside Xcode.) As the script works in Terminal, it's likely that Platypus's config is wrong somehow.

As a quick hack, I suppose you could symlink Python.framework from /Library/Frameworks to the Frameworks folder inside Xcode.

As stated in the comments, you don't need to include the first `import` line. Currently, you're importing all of `tkinter`, and then importing just the `filedialog`. The whole point of `from` is to avoid importing the entire library.