# Unable to run IDLE: No module named '_tkinter'

Tags: python, linux, tkinter, pip, fedora

when i run "idle3.8" i get this error:

```
 IDLE can't import Tkinter.
   Your Python may not be configured for Tk.
```

I have installed every tkinter packages but i get this error again.
and when I have imported tkinter and I get this error:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/tkinter/__init__.py", line 36, in <module>
    import _tkinter # If this fails your Python may not be configured for Tk
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_tkinter'
```

But I can import tkinter on python 2

- my operating system is fedora
- my python version is:3.8.2

Comment: Are you specifying python 3 when you install it?

Comment: Are you making sure you are saying tkinter and not Tkinter as Tkinter is for python 2

Comment: really?is tkinter foir python 2

Comment: I specify Python 3 when installing

Comment: Get some knowledge from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48385116/import-tkinter-or-tkinter) and get right understanding about what do you need to do.

Answer (score 2):

Here is **step by step guide** to make IDLE and `tkinter` work on macOS Catalina. Should be easily adapted to Linux:

1. install `tcl-tk` with Homebrew. In shell run `brew install tcl-tk`
2. in shell run `echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/tcl-tk/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc`
3. reload shell by quitting `Terminal` app or run `source ~/.zshrc`
4. after reloaded check that `tck-tk` is in `$PATH`. Run `echo $PATH | grep --color=auto tcl-tk`. As the result you should see your $PATH contents with `tcl-tk` highlighted
5. now we run three commands from Homebrew's output from step #1

   1. in shell run `export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/tcl-tk/lib"`
   2. in shell run `export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/tcl-tk/include"`
   3. in shell run `export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/opt/tcl-tk/lib/pkgconfig"`
6. if you have your Python version already installed with `pyenv` then uninstall it with `pyenv uninstall <your python version>`. E.g. `pyenv uninstall 3.8.2`
7. set environment variable that will be used by `python-build`. In shell run `PYTHON_CONFIGURE_OPTS="--with-tcltk-includes='-I/usr/local/opt/tcl-tk/include' --with-tcltk-libs='-L/usr/local/opt/tcl-tk/lib -ltcl8.6 -ltk8.6'"`
   *Note: in future use `tck-tk` version that actually installed with Homebrew. At the moment of posting `8.6` was the actual*
8. finally install Python with `pyenv` with `pyenv install <version>`. E.g. `pyenv install 3.8.2`

**Test**

1. in shell run `pyenv global <verion that you've just installed>`
2. now check IDLE. In shell run `idle`. You should see IDLE window without any warnings and "text printed in red".

[image: IDLE window run from Terminal. No warnings]

3. now check `tkinter`. In shell run `python -m tkinter -c "tkinter._test()"`. You should see test window like on the image:

[image: tkinter test window]

That's it!

**My environment:**

check this is something went wrong executing steps above:

1. macOS Catalina
2. `zsh` (included in macOS Catalina) = **"shell" above**
3. Homebrew (installed with instructions from Homebrew official website)
4. `pyenv` (installed with Homebrew and PATH updated according to `pyenv` official readme from GitHub)
5. Python `3.8.x` - `3.9.x` (installed with `pyenv install <version>` command)